# change background when radio button clicked

Tags: html, css

I have a radio button which i have given some style.

when i click on it then the div background color should change.

```css
.no_of_speakers_radio_button {
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: flex;
 padding: 35px 0px;
 text-align: center;
 flex-direction: column;
 border:thin red solid;
 width:100px;
}

.no_of_speakers_radio_button label {
 overflow: hidden;
}

.no_of_speakers_radio_button label span {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 15px;
 margin: auto;
 display: block;
}

.no_of_speakers_radio_button input {
 position: absolute;
}

.no_of_speakers_radio_button input:checked + span {
 background-color: #ebeff1;
 text-align: center;
}

.no_of_speakers_radio_button input:not(:checked + span) {
 background: transparent;
}

.no_of_speakers_radio_button:hover{
 background: #ebeff1;
}
```

```html
<div class="no_of_speakers_radio_button">
    <label class="four_speakers">
        <input type="radio" name="choose_speaker" class="click">
        <span class="font_size_20">4</span>
        <span class="font_size_17">Speakers</span>
    </label>
</div>

<div class="no_of_speakers_radio_button">
    <label class="eight_speakers">
        <input type="radio" name="choose_speaker" class="click">
        <span class="font_size_20">8</span>
        <span class="font_size_17">Speakers</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

What i want is, when clicking on radio button then whole div background should change rather than changing only span background.
[image: Just like in the image]

Thank you.

Comment: Add a parent container and have the CSS affect its child?

Comment: didn't get you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With pure css, you can't select a parent element from within a child
>   element

### Approach #01 (Without HTML Modifications):

Without modifying current `HTML` structure, you can use `:before` or `:after` pseudo element to create a fake active state.

You will need to add following CSS:

```
.no_of_speakers_radio_button {
  position: relative;
}
.no_of_speakers_radio_button input:checked + span:before {
  background-color: #ebeff1;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```css
.no_of_speakers_radio_button {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  padding: 35px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border:thin red solid;
  position: relative;
  width:100px;
}

.no_of_speakers_radio_button label {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.no_of_speakers_radio_button label span {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}

.no_of_speakers_radio_button input {
  position: absolute;
}

.no_of_speakers_radio_button input:checked + span {
  background-color: #ebeff1;
  text-align: center;
}

.no_of_speakers_radio_button input:checked + span:before {
  background-color: #ebeff1;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.no_of_speakers_radio_button input:not(:checked + span) {
  background: transparent;
}

.no_of_speakers_radio_button:hover{
  background: #ebeff1;
}
```

```html
<div class="no_of_speakers_radio_button">
  <label class="four_speakers">
    <input type="radio" name="choose_speaker" class="click">
    <span class="font_size_20">4</span>
    <span class="font_size_17">Speakers</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="no_of_speakers_radio_button">
  <label class="eight_speakers">
    <input type="radio" name="choose_speaker" class="click">
    <span class="font_size_20">8</span>
    <span class="font_size_17">Speakers</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

### Alternate Approach (With HTML Modification):

You can modify your `HTML` to the code below. The trick is to place original `input` out of the view and place a fake `input[type="radio"]`  button in place.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="no_of_speakers_radio_button">
  <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="choose_speaker" class="click">
  <label class="four_speakers" for="radio1">
    <div>
      <span class="font_size_20">4</span>
      <span class="fake-radio"></span>
    </div>
    <span class="font_size_17">Speakers</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.no_of_speakers_radio_button input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  left: -9999px;
  top: -9999px;
}
.no_of_speakers_radio_button label .fake-radio {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
}
.no_of_speakers_radio_button label .fake-radio:before {
  background-color: #222;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  content: '';
  bottom: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  top: 2px;
}
.no_of_speakers_radio_button input:checked + label .fake-radio:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```css
.no_of_speakers_radio_button {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border:thin red solid;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width:100px;
}

.no_of_speakers_radio_button label {
  padding: 35px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.no_of_speakers_radio_button div span {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.no_of_speakers_radio_button input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  left: -9999px;
  top: -9999px;
}

.no_of_speakers_radio_button label .fake-radio {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
}
.no_of_speakers_radio_button label .fake-radio:before {
  background-color: #222;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  content: '';
  bottom: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  top: 2px;
}
.no_of_speakers_radio_button input:checked + label {
  background-color: #ebeff1;
}
.no_of_speakers_radio_button input:checked + label .fake-radio:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
.no_of_speakers_radio_button input:not(:checked + span) {
  background: transparent;
}
.no_of_speakers_radio_button label:hover {
  background: #ebeff1;
}
```

```html
<div class="no_of_speakers_radio_button">
  <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="choose_speaker" class="click">
  <label class="four_speakers" for="radio1">
    <div>
      <span class="font_size_20">4</span>
      <span class="fake-radio"></span>
    </div>
    <span class="font_size_17">Speakers</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="no_of_speakers_radio_button">
  <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="choose_speaker" class="click">
  <label class="eight_speakers" for="radio2">
    <div>
      <span class="font_size_20">8</span>
      <span class="fake-radio"></span>
    </div>
    <span class="font_size_17">Speakers</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="no_of_speakers_radio_button">
  <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="choose_speaker" class="click">
  <label class="eight_speakers" for="radio3">
    <div>
      <span class="font_size_20">8</span>
      <span class="fake-radio"></span>
    </div>
    <span class="font_size_17">Speakers</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="no_of_speakers_radio_button">
  <input type="radio" id="radio4" name="choose_speaker" class="click">
  <label class="eight_speakers" for="radio4">
    <div>
      <span class="font_size_20">8</span>
      <span class="fake-radio"></span>
    </div>
    <span class="font_size_17">Speakers</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="no_of_speakers_radio_button">
  <input type="radio" id="radio5" name="choose_speaker" class="click">
  <label class="eight_speakers" for="radio5">
    <div>
      <span class="font_size_20">8</span>
      <span class="fake-radio"></span>
    </div>
    <span class="font_size_17">Speakers</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you.. but can't i make the whole div to be radio button. as user might not click on radio text. he can click anywhere in the whole div.

Comment: @Rishi Yes, it is possible, but the position of `input` box within the box might be tricky or difficult to position on exactly this place.

Comment: @Rishi I've update my answer. I hope it will solve all your problem.

Comment: in your second approach when i click on it then the page navigates to the top of it.

Comment: @Rishi hmm, let me try to figure out why it is happening.

Comment: @Rishi Please create a local example and check in browser. I'm not sure why it is moving page in code snippet. I've checked in my browser local and its working fine.

Comment: yes.. i just have checked in my browser and it worked fine.. but the only thing is when i click on the text changes to white and border is changed to light orange color.

Comment: i don't want any changes in css while clicking

Comment: @Rishi in which browser this is happening?

Comment: i m using mozilla firefox in my ubuntu

Comment: @Rishi I'm using Windows and I've not observed any such issue. However you can apply some `color` value and `outline: none` on `label:active` and `label:focus` styles to override any default styles that are being applied. It will fix styling problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132103/discussion-between-rishi-and-muhammad-usman).

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery for this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
   $('.no_of_speakers_radio_button input[type="radio"]').click(function() { 
   $(this).parent().parent().addClass("selected");
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
 .no_of_speakers_radio_button.selected {
   background: #ebeff1;
 }
```

Comment: not working. can't i make the whole div as radio button and clicking on it the background will get changed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot traverse a parent in css i.e. there is no parent-selector.

However you can modify your html structure and style it in such a way as to achieve what you want here. I have modified your code a little bit here:

```css
.no_of_speakers_radio_button {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: thin red solid;
  width: 100px;
}
.no_of_speakers_radio_button label {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.no_of_speakers_radio_button label span {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}
.no_of_speakers_radio_button input {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.no_of_speakers_radio_button input:checked + span {
  background-color: #ebeff1;
  text-align: center;
}
.no_of_speakers_radio_button input:not(:checked + span) {
  background: transparent;
}
.no_of_speakers_radio_button:hover {
  background: #ebeff1;
}
.font_size_20 {
  height: 60px;
  padding-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="no_of_speakers_radio_button">
  <label class="four_speakers">
    <input type="radio" name="choose_speaker" class="click">
    <span class="font_size_20">4 <span>Speakers</span> </span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="no_of_speakers_radio_button">
  <label class="eight_speakers">
    <input type="radio" name="choose_speaker" class="click">
    <span class="font_size_20">8 <span>Speakers</span></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: i might have more than one span text. like. **4** and **speakers**

Comment: @Rishi You can nest your spans within the main span. Updated my answer.

Comment: thank you.. but it is still not same as i want it to be.

Comment: I don't know what you want then. You should mention your exact requirements in the description.

Comment: sorry to be unclear. as shown in the image. i want a radio button look like a div and when i hover or click on it then it's background color should change .

Comment: Here the `span`s are indeed behaving as radio buttons. You click anywhere inside the span the corresponding radio button is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Using css there is no click trigger. However you can use javascript for click function to toggle background color

```js
var radio1 = document.getElementsByClassName("click")[0];
var radio2 = document.getElementsByClassName("click")[1];
 radio1.addEventListener("click",function(){
  radio1.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor="red";
  radio2.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor="white";
 })
radio2.addEventListener("click",function(){
  radio2.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor="red";
  radio1.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor="white";
 })
```

```css
.no_of_speakers_radio_button {
   margin: 0 auto;
   display: flex;
   padding: 35px 0px;
   text-align: center;
   flex-direction: column;
   border:thin red solid;
   width:100px;
  }

  .no_of_speakers_radio_button label {
   overflow: hidden;
  }

  .no_of_speakers_radio_button label span {
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 15px;
   margin: auto;
   display: block;
  }

  .no_of_speakers_radio_button input {
   position: absolute;
  }

  .no_of_speakers_radio_button input:checked + span {
   text-align: center;
  }

  .no_of_speakers_radio_button input:not(:checked + span) {
   background: transparent;
  }

  .no_of_speakers_radio_button:hover{
   background: #ebeff1;
  }
```

```html
<div class="no_of_speakers_radio_button" class="four_speakers">
 <label >
  <input type="radio" name="choose_speaker" class="click" >
  <span class="font_size_20">4</span>
  <span class="font_size_17">Speakers</span>
 </label>
</div>

<div class="no_of_speakers_radio_button">
 <label class="eight_speakers">
  <input type="radio" name="choose_speaker" class="click">
  <span class="font_size_20">8</span>
  <span class="font_size_17">Speakers</span>
 </label>
</div>
```

Comment: want to do it without using javascript or jquery.

Answer (score 0):

give a radio button a class name and in that class just put change background